# Can I program microcontroller PIC 18F4550 with matlab?

Tags: matlab, microcontroller, pic18

I'm devellping a line follower robot with PIC 18F4550 using Pic C compiler software , but I want to get more precision by the robot while following the line...

Can I use matlab to program this microcontoller or what is the best software that gives me the best quality and performance for line following.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you install Matlab on a PIC 18F4550? ;-)

Comment: Of course no , neither PIC C COMPILER but I'm programming my pic with this software , it generates a (.hex) file that I uploade to my pic and it works...

Comment: Ummm... it is an interesting question.... I never got aware of having MATLAB as compiling hex language, i ussualy stand by having a PIC C Compiler but never went far beyond that... Did you seek on the web?.

Comment: @Donda of course the question is to generate an HEX file for the PIC from Matlab XD...

Comment: I guess the compiling platform, though, has **nothing** to do with the precision on following the line... having anything instead of a standard C Compiler **will not** improve a bad illuminated IR or Laser sensor against a white tape on the floor.......

Comment: I doubt it. You can develop in matlab language and turn the code into c which with a little work should compile. But if you use any but the most trivial functions the requirements on memory and speed quickly explode.

Comment: @ Hypfco No I didn't see in the web , I got the question in my mind and I posted it only here... I just want to get more precision and if I can correction for the robot to follow the line rapidly so I thinked in matlab.
@ Bdecaf : Thank you I'll try to develop in matlab and convert to c and see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I have been working a few years with pic18 mcus and i haver never hear about that.